# Can I suppress update notices for apps that require a greater iOS version than my iPad supports?

Tags: ipad

I am using an iPad 1 with various apps installed. When I get app update notifications, the app may be greyed out because it requires iOS 6, which the iPad 1 does not support. These update notices always remain on my iPad - is there some way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - iOS 6 and lower have no provision to hide updates for apps that are live on the store and a higher version than what you have installed.